# PHP 5.3: "Declaration of ... should be compatible with that of ..." error

Tags: error-handling, php, php-ini

After having upgraded to PHP 5.3, my application was inundated with

> "Declaration of ... should be compatible with that of ..."

style errors. I understand the nature of these errors, but I wish to disable them.

The [`error_reporting` setting in php.ini](http://php.net/errorfunc.configuration) is `"E_ALL & ~(E_NOTICE | E_DEPRECATED)"`, but this error continues to show up.  I assumed it was included in `E_STRICT`, but am I wrong?

Comment: Doesn't it say what type of error it is?

Comment: These are indeed `E_STRICT` errors, but but IMO you should fix their causes instead of their reporting. Keep your code clean.

Comment: It's not a matter of clean code.  The error is the result of a child class's method having extra arguments than the same method in the parent class.  In particular, it's a _defaultAction() function for a controller class.  The extended default actions may very well accept arguments the parent class does not.  I could easily use func_get_args() to circumvent the issue, but then the method declaration is entirely devoid of relevant meaning.

Answer (score 12):

It's an [`E_STRICT`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) error.  Change your php.ini setting to `E_ALL & ~(E_NOTICE | E_DEPRECATED | E_STRICT)`...

But it should be turned off by default (it's not included in `E_ALL`).  So if you're getting them, that means it's being turned on somewhere.  The question is, where?  Do declare `error_reporting(...)` anywhere in your files?  If so, check them.  If not, then be sure you're editing the right php.ini file (check `phpinfo()`)...  You could always do a `grep` for `E_STRICT` to try to find where it's being turned on...

Comment: it could also be enabled by using `error_reporting(-1)` which is the recommended way of enabling all errors on development machines.

Comment: I changed the setting in php.ini, but the error still appears.  It isn't set anywhere else (checked via grep) and altering the error_reporting value at runtime has no effect.  Also, the line referenced in the error is always the line where the child class is declared, if this sheds any light on the problem.

Comment: For completeness, `E_STRICT` *is* included in `E_ALL` as of 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you a good settings.

You can change `php.ini`, in this file, you can search a sentence as `ignore_repeated_errors = Off`, you should change off state to on state.

If you also meet the same type of error, you should set *Error Level Constants*.