# Yii2 Declaration beforeAction should be compatible with Controller

Tags: php, yii2

Whenever I include the `beforeAction` function event with something simple I get an error saying it has to be compatible. This does not happen on my live server only on my local one. The only difference I can think of is my local server is running PHP7 and my live one is running PHP5.6. Is that what is causing the issue? The only thing I have found that will fix it is removing it completely.

This is what my `beforeAction` looks like

```
 public function beforeAction()
    { 
        if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
            return $this->redirect(['site/login']);
        } else {
            if(strtotime(UserInfo::findOne(Yii::$app->user->Id)->active_until) < strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))){
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('warning', 'You need an active subscription to access events.');
                echo("<script>location.href = '".Url::toRoute('site/subscription')."';</script>");
                exit;
                //return $this->redirect(['site/subscription']);
            }else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I also tried this simple one to check and got the same issue

```
public function beforeAction()
    {
        if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Here is the error message I get

```
Declaration of frontend\controllers\EventController::beforeAction() should be compatible with yii\web\Controller::beforeAction($action)
```

Comment: tried this? return parent::beforeAction($action);

Comment: yes I have also tried that

Comment: hope this will help.. ran out of ideas haha. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017193/php-5-3-declaration-of-should-be-compatible-with-that-of-error

Comment: just tried that and still getting that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this error message :

```
should be compatible with yii\web\Controller::beforeAction($action)
```

Your override function must be compatible with parent. So, valid code :

```
public function beforeAction($action)
    { 
        ....
    }
```

Comment: At first I didn't see how it was different, ugh just left out $action. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Just explaining

If you get this problem, it means that you have a function in your parent class  and a function in your child class that have the same name but not the same input variable declaration.

Parent Class

```
beforeAction($action) {
....
}
```

Child Class

```
beforeAction() {
....
}
```

As you can see, the child class is missing the $action variable. This creates a warning in PHP E_Strict. All you have to do is make sure that the child class function is exactly the same as the parent.